# how to bypass robots.txt while crawling

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone please tell me if there is any way to ignore or bypass robots.txt while crawling. Is there any way to modify script in such way that it ignores robots.txt and go on with crawling?

Or is there any other way to achieve the same?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow:
```

Comment: `robots.txt` is a suggestion, not a requirement. If you want to ignore it, you just ignore it.

Comment: Maybe you have problems with Cross-Origin-Requests, not with `robots.txt`?

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing a crawler then you have complete control of it. You can make it behave nicely or you can make it behave badly.

If you don't want your crawler to respect robots.txt then just write it so it doesn't. You might be using a library that respects robots.txt automatically, if so then you will have to disable that (which will usually be an option you pass to the library when you call it).

---

There is no way to use client side JavaScript to cause a crawler reading the page embedding the JS to stop respecting robots.txt.

Comment: But doesn't it create the risk of a 403 forbidden access?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica — It's possible that if you write a badly behaved bot then a site will apply a heuristic approach to blocking you. That's a risk you take when you ignore a polite Keep Out notice.

Answer (score 3):

if you are writing Crawler in mechanize (Python) and have an interface with robot.txt
then use the following command:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
```

Comment: that's really helpful